# setSize() for jpanel not working

Tags: swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel, awt

i am trying to set the width and height of JPanel.But it is not working.
Here's the code.

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FirstGuiApp extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("first gui app");
        JPanel txtPanel = new JPanel();
        txtPanel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        txtPanel.setSize(200,50);// **not working**

        frm.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH,txtPanel);
        frm.setVisible(true);
        frm.setSize(450, 350);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Not able to understand the mistake..

Comment: Don't use setSize(). Each component has a preferred size that the layout manager uses as a guideline to size components. Each layout manager can use/ignored the preferred size depending on the rules of the layout manager. 

So When you add components to the panel it will have a preferred size automatically. 

There is no reason to play with the size of an empty panel.

Comment: so...in the current context..is it not possible to increase the size of jpanel..??

Comment: You can override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the JPanel. But don't do this! Learn how to use Swing properly. The panel is empty so there is no need to do this. Ask a real life question and then I can give you an appropriate solution. The point of using layout managers is that you don't have to guess what an appropriate size for a panel should be.

Comment: *"Not able to understand the mistake.."*  Not able to discern your question.  What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

try using     `frm.getContentPane().add(txtPanel)` or  `frm.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,txtPanel);`

The components are laid out according to their preferred sizes and the constraints of the container's size. The NORTH and SOUTH components may be stretched horizontally; the EAST and WEST components may be stretched vertically; the CENTER component may stretch both horizontally and vertically to fill any space left over.

Thus you have to add the component to Center which is default if you don't give the constraint.Sorry we can not grow the positions.

Comment: how to set the north portion to grow accordingly..??

Comment: @Narendra I edited the answer.Sorry for the idea to grow it which is impossible